# Restarting window manager blackout

Tags: shutdown, display-manager

I wanted to restart the window manager so I issued `sudo service lightdm restart` but then the screen went black, the case speaker beeped once and that's it. I pressed the power button (once) the computer was turned off (almost immediately).

Anyone knows what's going on?

p.s: I already have [some issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592113/computer-shutdown-time-is-longer-than-it-should) with shutting down. I think they're related. Can anyone diagnose these issues or what they're related for or what I should search for? Any ideas?